# next js - the style of the tailwind class i get from API doesnt apply on my element

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

i have a problem. i use an api to get a `bg tailwind` class and i use that to style an element. the class text will be added to the classlists of my element but the style of this class doesnt apply on my element. these are my codes:
my _app.js component

```
    //_app.js component
    import "../index.css";
    import Navigation from "../components/Navigation/Navigation";
    import navItems from "../data/NavItems.json";
    
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, datas }) {
      console.log(datas);
      return (
        <>
          <Navigation items={navItems} bg={datas[0]} />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
      );
    }
    
    MyApp.getInitialProps = async () => {
      const datas = await fetch(
        "https://*.co/rest/v1/colors?select=color",
        {
          headers: {
            apikey:"*",
            Authorization:
              "*",
          },
        }
      )
        .then((datas) => datas.json())
        .then((value) => value);
    
      return { datas };
    };
    
    export default MyApp;
```

i use the class in my navigation component:

```
//Navigation component
import NavItems from "./NavItems";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";

const Navigation = ({ items, bg }) => {
  return (
    <nav className={`left-0 right-0 h-[80px] fixed shadow-[0px_4px_14px_rgba(0,0,0,0.08)] flex justify-between items-center p-[10px] ${bg.color}`}>
      <SearchBar />
      <NavItems items={items} />
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

so do you have any idea about solving this problem?

---

note: the `bg colors` in this api are not something specific. these datas can be anything. so adding my colors to `tailwind.config.js` cant help.

Comment: What is the shape of the data you get from your endpoint? Could you set the background color as an inline style instead?

Comment: the shape of datas are exactly the same with tailwind classes. for example in this situation, the shape of datas are `bg-[a hex code]`. i can set inline styles, but my website has a lot of customization options and i should set hundreds or even thousends inline styles and i think its not the best and standard way. dont you have other ideas to style my customizable elements in the best and standard ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tailwind generates classes at build time to form the CSS stylesheets. These stylesheets then cannot magically contain these classes from the request. I would suggest using [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and then using these CSS custom properties within the Tailwind classes, like `bg-[color:var(--color)]`.

Comment: but think that i am creating a note app. user can create as many notes as he/she wants. user can choose a specific color for each of the notes. and user can save the notes in database. so in this situation, using a `css variable` is not useful. because we dont know how many papers will user create. whats would you do if you were in this situation?

Comment: CSS variables can still work here, you place the CSS variable(s) on the corresponding note. So each note can have the same CSS variable but different values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you solved this problem, but I solved mine, here is what I did.

1- I added a content configuration like this:

content: [
.
.
.
"./tailwind-safelist.txt",
],

2- You need to expose all used classes inside your backend, I made an API that returns every class used in the database.

3- From the front-end, fetch the classes, and dynamically create 'tailwind-safelist.txt'

This is assuming that no new classes are added after building. But this is the closest solution right now.